# How to apply hover and formatting simultaneously to QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I'm trying to change background color of QPushButton element when hovered. Also, I need to keep my formatting in the stylesheet, but could not do it together as it does not render in the GUI.

Here is what I want to keep (the START LISTENING button):
[image]

With the following stylesheet, I can attain changing background-color on hover, but rest of the formatting part does not work:

```
QPushButton::hover#start_stop_button
{
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
border-color:rgb(60, 231, 195);
border-style:outset;color:lightgrey;border-width:2px;border-radius: 12px;padding: 6px;background-color: rgb(50, 50, 100);
```

This is what I get instead (when not hovered on START LISTENING button):
[image]

Comment: I think you just need to put all three function calls within the curly braces of the hover code.

Comment: Does not work as expected :(

Answer (score 1):

You have put two different colors in your style, and the last color, which is the same color as the background color, has been taken, and you have not put the entire code inside the parentheses

try this code:

```
QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: rgb(60, 231, 195);
    border-style: outset;
    color: lightgrey;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```